# Segmentation fault in C not occuring

Tags: c, atom-editor

<kbd>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)#C.23)</kbd> gives below example

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
char *p2;
*p2='b';
return 0;

}
```

and says it should cause Segmentation fault ,quoting below reason

> Here, p2 may point to anywhere in memory, so performing the assignment *p2 = 'b'; can corrupt an unknown area of memory or trigger a segmentation fault.

But while running this in Atom ,i am not getting any error.I am getting blank command prompt

Any ideas on this

Comment: This code is undefined behavior: it may trigger a segmentation fault or just run without crashing as well

Comment: It may point anywhere in memory, so it might happen to point somewhere valid.

Comment: Quote from your quote: '_may_ point to <...>, _can_ <...> trigger a segfault".

Comment: @MichaelBurr:thanks,so if i continue to run many times,this may cause Segfault right ?

Comment: a downvote for wikipedia ;)

Comment: You'd have more luck using `char *p2=NULL;`

Comment: Contrary to your assertion, the Wikipedia article you reference *does not* say that dereferencing a wild pointer as your code does should cause a segmentation fault.  It says "The result ***is often*** a segmentation fault, storage violation or wild branch" (emphasis added).  It does not clearly say that the behavior is undefined, but that's the case.  Since it's undefined, you cannot rely on a segfault any more than you can rely on any other behavior.

Comment: don't learn to write code that'll crash - learn to write code that'll work :)

Comment: @chris: I think it's part of learning curve to know what errors can occur

Comment: @LPs  won't that be null reference exception

Comment: @JohnBollinger:It does in the dangling pointer section

Comment: Dereferencing a null pointer is UB like wiki example. I suggested it because mainly you can see segmentation fault in your console.

Comment: @TheGameiswar: running it multiple times will more likely just keep doing the same thing as it is now.  The value of the pointer is indeterminate - it could be anything. But chances are that that stack location happens to be used for something in the code that sets things up for calling main, so it's likely that it will always have the same indeterminate value.

Comment: @TheGameiswar, no, it doesn't say so in the dangling pointer section, either.  As ForceBru already observed, there it says that your faulty code *can* cause a segmentation fault, not that it *will* do so.

Comment: @JohnBollinger:Thanks

Comment: Agreeing with previous comments, I add that this code probably don't crash because a pointer has 4 or 8 bytes of length (architecture x86 or x64), and you are saving just 1 byte value. Experiment to save a word with more than 8 bytes and you probably will see the error you expect. But keep in mind the real meaning of pointer. And like the previous comments said, always write a defensive code.

Answer (score 0):

as you mentioned, p2 can point anywhere. you get a segmentation fault error when you try to modify the part of memory that does not belong to the memory that the OS has given to you to run your program. so if you don't get a seg fault it means that this pointer is pointing to an address that belongs to your memory. if you repeat running this code, you may get a seg fault.